# C code doesn't work with but no errors

Tags: c, string, logic

I am writing the following code to reverse the string, without reversing the words. For e.g.
I/P: This is sparta
O/P: sparta is This

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{   
    char a[50],b[50];
    int i,j,k,l;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",a);
    l=strlen(a);
    i=0;j=l-1;
ae: 
    for(i;;i++)
        if(a[i]==' ' || a[i]=='\0')
            break;
    k=i;
    for(j;;j--,k--)
    {
        if(a[k]==' ' || k==0)
            break;
        else
            b[j]=a[k-1];
    }
    if(strlen(b)!=l) goto ae;
    else 
        printf("%s",b);
    getch();
}
```

This code runs wihout errors but after accepting the string, it doesn't go further at all. The terminal gets kinda hanged. I don't know whats the problem. Please help.

Comment: why you are using `%[^\n]s` to read?

Comment: You have two `for` loops with no stop condition **in either one of them**, what did you expect???

Comment: To read a string, of course. I even used gets(). But the same problem is ecountered

Comment: It breaks inside the loop, that's why? @barakmanos

Comment: `a[i]==' '` no change codition, when a[i] : ' '.

Comment: Well if it "gets kinda hanged" then they probably don't quite break now do they? Run it step-by-step with a debugger.

Comment: other than the non terminating loop, you might also want to stop using goto. Here's what happens if you use goto -> http://xkcd.com/292/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged your program and the problem i found is that your program is entering into a never ending loop.

```
for(i;;i++)
    if(a[i]==' ' || a[i]=='\0')
        break;
```

the above loop breaks at  i=4 when a[i] was equal to ' '.
Later after goto is executed,i is still 4 and when

```
if(a[i]==' ' || a[i]=='\0')
        break;
```

is evaluated i remains 4 and therefore again breaks from the loop.Thus leading to a endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is an infinite loop if the entered string contains a space.

1. Iterate over the string `a` until `a[i] == ' '`.
2. `k = i;`
3. Immediately break out of the second `for` loop because `a[i] == ' '` and `k == i` implies `a[k] == ' '`.
4. `b` is uninitialized but `strlen(b) != l` will be true with high probability and therefore the branch `goto ae;` will be taken and the infinite loop is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The format string in `scanf("%[^\n]s",a);` is made up of two parts: `"%[^\n]"` and `"s"`.

The first part expects a sequence of characters different than `'\n'` and writes them in the corresponding address.

The second part expects a literal `'s'` and discards it.

With the input "This is sparta\n" the `scanf()` isn't terminated. It is still looking for an `'s'`.

Comment: doesn't `s` stand for `string` and not the literal `'s'` ?? AFAIK, `"%[^\n]s"` is just one part - string that matches the expression `[^\n]`. I could be wrong.

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan: you are wrong. `"%s"` stand for a string; `"%[...]"` stands for a scanset; `"%[...]s"` stands for a scanset followed by a literal `'s'`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html

Comment: I tried removing scanf and tried using gets function. The problem still exists.

Comment: No. The scanf() call terminates as soon as a newline is found. It doesn't look for `s`. It could very well be `scanf("%[^\n]Hi Good morning from UK",a);`.

Comment: I would use `if (scanf("%49[^\n]", a) != 1) /* error */;` to prevent buffer overflows and detect errors in the input data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot safely use `strlen(b)`, since the characters in `b` are not initialized to 0.

So to begin with, change `b[50]` to `b[50] = {0}`.